# R Studio-Error when trying to download new packages after win10 update

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently downloaded the new win10 updates and for some reason it's blocking me from downloading new packages in R. Here is the error:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

> Warning in install.packages :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection
>   with the server could not be established'

Here is my solution that didn't work. Downloading from CRAN:

```
name <- ("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library")
download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr", destfile = name)


Error in download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr", destfile 
= name) :cannot open destfile 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library', reason 
'Permission denied'
```

Any solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1**

Run your rStudio as administrator

**Solution #2**

Changing the security setting on the R folder to "full control"

[Here](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/) you can see how to change folder permissions

Comment: I tried both solutions and get the same error. Any other ideas? thanks

Comment: can use try to run `options(download.file.method="libcurl")` before download package and see what result you get?